# Hide SQL statements when running IPython notebook with Django's django-extensions

Tags: sql, django, ipython, jupyter-notebook, django-extensions

I'm using Django's django-extensions to run an iPython notebook with access to the Django models (as detailed here http://andrewbrookins.com/python/using-ipython-notebook-with-django/). When I make model queries, the notebook shows the underlying SQL queries executed by Django, like so:

[image]

Can I hide this SQL? It's so voluminous it makes the display unusable at times.

Answer (score 0):

with recent version, you could use

```
%%capture variable
the code
```

to capture stdout and stderr into a variable
adding the --no-stdout flag

```
%%capture --no-stdout variable
```

wont capture stdout, thus displaying it.

Also, please, IPython (upper casse I) preferably,
ipython accepted, but try to avoid iPython