# Print sql queries in jupyter notebook with django-extensions plugin

Tags: django, ipython, jupyter-notebook, manage.py, django-extensions

Is it possible to show SQL queries like in this command: `python manage.py shell_plus --print-sql` but in Jupyter Notebook?

I tried this command `python manage.py shell_plus --notebook --print-sql` but it not worked.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a bug in Django Extensions that you don't see SQL queries. A few versions ago, someone [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738163/hide-sql-statements-when-running-ipython-notebook-with-djangos-django-extension) how to disable SQL printing in Jupyter.

As a workaround, you could use [django_print_sql](https://pypi.org/project/django-print-sql/):

```
from django_print_sql import print_sql
with print_sql(count_only=False):
    User.objects.count()
```

You may even find that having control over which queries to print is preferable to printing all.

But I mostly just print the last query retroactively:

```
from django import db
db.connection.queries[-1]
```

If you want to pretty-print the query with [sqlparse](https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/), it starts getting complicated enough for a utility function:

```
import sqlparse
sqlparse.format(
    db.connection.queries[-1]['sql'], 
    reindent=True, 
    keyword_case='upper'
)
```